# How to use method as predicate in the in Predicate Query in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, repository-pattern

I have a method in repository and  where i have implemeted a method which return all open order shifts

```
 public async Task<IList<OrderShift>> GetAllOpenOrderShift()
        {
            return await GetAllAsync(a => a.Status == OrderShift.ShiftOpen).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

also i have create method in the entity
like

```
   public virtual bool IsOpen()
        {
            return Status == ShiftOpen;
        }
```

but when i try to use method in the predicate i get error  like

```
InvalidOperationException: Unrecognised method call: App/Entity/OrderShift : Boolean IsOpen()
```

How  can i use method as  predicate in the  those repo method.

Recently i have used the solution that works fine but to implement more than one   conditions in predicate query, should i have to create expression in the  entity or what should i have to do?

```
  public async Task<OrderShift?> GetShiftByStartingUserId(long userId)
        {
            return await CurrentSession.QueryOver<OrderShift>()
     .Where(a => userId == a.StartedByUserId && a.Status == OrderShift.StatusOpen).SingleOrDefaultAsync();         
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provider must be able to convert the expression tree to SQL; generally user-defined methods will not be supported.

You could, however, do something like this:

```
class Repository
{
    public async Task<IList<OrderShift>> GetAllOpenOrderShift()
    {
        return await GetAllAsync(OrderShift.IsOpenExpression).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public class OrderShift()
{
    internal static Expression<Func<OrderShift, bool>> IsOpenExpression =>
        a => a.Status == ShiftOpen;

    public virtual bool IsOpen()
    {
        return IsOpenExpression.Compile()(this);
    }
}
```